# How To Use A WPF Window To Launch An Application From Desktop Folder On Any Machine

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, launch

I  keep searching the Internet for some sort of tutorial on this but none I've fount make it very clear.
I've created a WPF Window in Visual Studio that has two Buttons
Button One Is to be used to launch a PDF File.
Button Two is to be used to launch the .exe application and then close the WPF window
Now I find that if I use:

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:/Users/mdkgr/Desktop/FolderName/app.exe")`

Then it works, however, naturally when I publish this project out and people are to use it on their machine this method will not work because the address will no doubt be different for every machine it's installed on.
My question is simply:
How do I make this so it will launch either the PDF file or application.exe on any machine it's installed on?
None of the Visual Studio tutorial I've seen make this very clear.

**Edit:**

I tried @bwing ' s idea but I get an error so I'm not sure if I'm using it right?? Here is my code in the public voids:

```
`public static void LaunchKOS()
        {
            var desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            // Launch Voice Server
            //Process.Start("C:/Users/mdkgr/Desktop/Knight O S Beta01_Data/voice-recognition-server-pc/VoiceServer/bin/Release/KittVoiceServer");

            var combinedPath = Path.Combine(desktopPath, "Knight O S Beta01_Data/voice-recognition-server-pc/VoiceServer/bin/Release/KittVoiceServer");
            Process.Start(combinedPath);

            // Launch Knight O.S. Unity Settings Window
            Process.Start("C:/Users/mdkgr/Desktop/Knight O S Beta01");
            // Close This Window
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        public static void LaunchPDF()
        {
            Process.Start("C:/Users/mdkgr/Desktop/Knight O S Beta01_Data/Knight O.S. Features.pdf");
        }`
```

**EDIT:**

This method is working just fine on one of my machines but as soon as I try it on my HP laptop it only wants to open the Unity3d application. and yet on both machines the folder directories are exactly the same and I can manually open each .exe files with no problems but my launcher application only wants to open the one .exe file on my HP laptop. Does anyone have any clue why this would be happening?

```css
public static void LaunchKOS()
        {
            

            var desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            var desktopPathkos = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            // Launch Voice Server
            var combinedPath = Path.Combine(desktopPath, "Knight O S Beta01_Data/voice-recognition-server-pc/VoiceServer/bin/Release/KittVoiceServer");
            Process.Start(combinedPath);
            // Launch Knight O.S. Unity Settings Window
            var combinedPathkos = Path.Combine(desktopPathkos, "Knight O S Beta01");
            Process.Start(combinedPathkos);

            
            // Close This Window
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
```

Comment: You can use `Environment.GetFolderPath` to get the path to the user's desktop. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Are you expecting that the app.exe and pdf will be in the same folder as the WPF Window you're using?

Comment: Thanks for responding Bradley,
So if I have my application in this case it's a Unity3d app on the desktop with it's data folder, if I place my PDF into that data folder this method will work on any machine so long as the files are located on the desktop?

Comment: bwing,
Yes, I think if I understand the way Visual Studio published the final file it places it in that bin or release folder, but if I copy those files to say my desktop where I'd have something like this:
Imagine this is my desktop:

Icon for Application launcher (WPF window)
Unity3d App.exe (Actual Application I want to launch with the WPF Window)

Folder (Unity data folder that I have placed the PDF File into)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files are on the desktop, you can get the path to the desktop with

```
var desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

If the files are in the same folder as the WPF Window application you can use this to get that folder

```
var exePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Then you just append the file name and make the call as you were before

```
var combinedPath = Path.Combine(desktopPath, "app.exe");
Process.Start(combinedPath
```

Comment: Thanks bwing, is this in C#?
I have my buttons reference a C# file I call "Launcher" and then each button calls a public void.

Comment: Yes, this is in C#. You will need to add     "using System.IO;"    to the to of the file to use the Path.Combine call.

Comment: Thanks @bwing
That did the trick, as soon as I added the "using System.IO;" it fixed the error.
Because I'm using that method to launch 2 different .exe files I had to copy it for each one and name the ""desktopPath" different for each one but it appears to work so far, I'll test it on a different machine to make sure.

Comment: OK this is a little strange, on the PC I'm building my launcher on it loads up both exe files, but on my 2nd PC it only loads up the Unity3d App exe??

Comment: Yes both of the executable files run if I click them manually on the 2nd PC.
I was just thinking, maybe it needs to be run in a coroutine where I fist have the voice server exe start and then perhaps a second later have the actual unity3d app open??